# Comparing two valus of Nodes in Binary search trees in java

Tags: java, tree, binary

hey I am new in the binary trees world and I am trying to compare to values to know which direction should I place the newly added node next.
for now, I tried to do CompareTo method but didn't succeed very much I am now trying to make a private method that will give me the value of the Nodes i would love some help
this is my code now I need to add to the if statement the comparing of nodes so I can proceed  :

```
public void add(E data) {
    if(root == null) {
        return ;
    }
    if(root.getLeftSon() == null) {
        root.setLeftSon((Node<E>) data);
    }
    else if(root.getRightSon() == null) {
        root.setRightSon((Node<E>) data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your data is of E type and I am assuming your root is of Node<E> type. Why are you casting the data to a Node<E> type? You could have each Node have a left and right children of Node type and a data field of type E. That way, you could create a node with a value of whatever type you want the tree to hold.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use generics correctly. Parameter has to extend comparable so you can determinate how to sort it.

```
class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    Node<T> root;

    public Node<T> addRecursive(Node<T> current, T value) {
        if (current == null) {
            return new Node<T>(value);
        }

        int ord = value.compareTo(current.value);

        if (ord > 0) {
            current.left = addRecursive(current.left, value);
        } else if (ord < 0) {
            current.right = addRecursive(current.right, value);
        } else {
            // value already exists
            return current;
        }

        return current;
    }

    static class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
        T value;
        Node<T> left;
        Node<T> right;

        Node(T value) {
            this.value = value;
            right = null;
            left = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To be perfect add the original `add` containing `root = addRecursive(root, value)`.